# Tabulate multiple levels for each column in dataframe

Tags: r

```
> head(Gene)
  Key Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
1   1   intergenic       intergenic   intergenic
2   2   intergenic       intergenic   intergenic
3   3   intergenic       intergenic     intronic
4   4       exonic           exonic       exonic
5   5   intergenic       intergenic     intronic
6   6   intergenic       intergenic     intronic
```

Required Output:

```
Type          Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
exonic             1              1                1
intergenic         5              5                2
intronic           0              0                3
```

The solution I tried is working on only one column:

```
unique(Gene["Func.ensGene"])
```

Could I get the output table as shown above and get a barplot
where X-axis has the 'Type' and the bar represents counts from each column?

Comment: `dput(head(Gene))` would have been better than just `head(Gene)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `?xtabs` along with `?stack`:

```
xtabs( ~ values + ind , stack(df1[,-1]))
```

or even shorter as @nicola suggests:

```
table(stack(df1[,-1]))
```

for both you get:

```
#            ind
#values       Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
#  exonic                1                1            1
#  intergenic            5                5            2
#  intronic              0                0            3
```

do you prefer further working on a data.frame?

```
as.data.frame.matrix(
    xtabs( ~ values + ind , stack(df1[,-1]))  # or again only table(stack(df1[,-1]))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get all `unique` levels from the dataframe and for every column calculate the count of each level by first converting it to `factor` with unique levels calculated before.

```
unique_names <- unique(unlist(df[-1]))
sapply(df[-1], function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique_names)))

#           Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
#intergenic            5                5            2
#exonic                1                1            1
#intronic              0                0            3
```

Answer (score 0):

Love the base R solutions but using `data.table` and some `magrittr` for readability you could get a data.frame directly (instead of a table):

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Key") %>%
  .[, .N, .(variable, value)] %>% 
  dcast(value ~ variable, value.var = "N", fill = 0)

        value Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
1:     exonic            1                1            1
2: intergenic            5                5            2
3:   intronic            0                0            3
```

Or much more concisely(as suggested by Henrik):

```
dcast(melt(df, "Key"), value ~ variable)
```

If you prefer tidyverse functions:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(key = Key) %>%
  group_by(Key, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(Key, n, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   value [3]
  value      Func.ensGene Func.genericGene Func.refGene
  <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>
1 exonic                1                1            1
2 intergenic            5                5            2
3 intronic              0                0            3
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Key              = 1:6, 
  Func.ensGene     = c("intergenic", "intergenic", "intergenic", "exonic", "intergenic", "intergenic"), 
  Func.genericGene = c("intergenic", "intergenic", "intergenic", "exonic", "intergenic", "intergenic"), 
  Func.refGene     = c("intergenic", "intergenic", "intronic", "exonic", "intronic", "intronic"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: For those who prefer poorer readability: `dcast(melt(df, "Key"), value ~ variable)`

Comment: Thanks @Henrik, I forgot about the summarising capabilities of `dcast()`.